# how to access content of mysqli result object directly?

Tags: php, database, object, mysqli

I am retrieving data using

```
$sql = "SELECT 'username', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'location' FROM 'userform' WHERE 'ID' = '$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

but unable to access as it has only one row so i am not using `foreach` or `$result->fetch_assoc()`. if i want to access the username from `$result` how should i do it ?

Comment: `$result->fetch_assoc()` is exactly how you would fetch a record from the result.  So why wouldn't you use that?  There are many tutorials and examples online of how to read data from a database in PHP.  What specifically are you trying and how is it failing?

Comment: `fetch_assoc` will be an array, not an object. Also don't quote columns/tables and use parameterized queries.

Comment: `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` helped. in one example it was used in a loop so didnt understood it. but now used it directly without while loop and works now. thank you. it was like this `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {...}`. i will have to read about fetch_assoc()

Comment: if i want to directly access the contents of `$result` object how can i?

Comment: @NilkamalGotarne: You would access the contents of `$result` by calling one of the functions on that object to return the information.  For example: `$result->fetch_assoc()`.  Or maybe `fetch_array()`, or `fetch_object()`, etc.  There are a variety of operations available: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: simply you cannot. clear enough?

Comment: You only need to call `fetch_assoc()` in a loop if you want to fetch multiple rows. If you just need one row, just call it once. But either way, you have to call it to get the data from the query.